# Ruby popen and executable path?

Tags: ruby, shell

When executing `IO.popen` or `exec`, where does Ruby pick up the default PATH variable from?

For example in zsh:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/bibstha/.rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

which confirms to `ENV['PATH']` in irb:

```
irb(main):026:0> ENV['PATH']
=> "/Users/bibstha/.rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

but not with `popen`:

```
irb(main):024:0> IO.popen("echo $PATH").read.chomp
=> "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

**Update**:

I've tried this with the ruby distributed with OSX Yosemite (10.10) as well as a custom install with ruby-install.

Homebrew installs a lot of applications in /usr/local/bin and since ruby does not have this in PATH, couple of my scripts are failing.

Comment: I am using rbenv and IO.popen("echo $PATH").read.chomp and ENV['PATH'] are exactly the same but echo $PATH from shell is different.

Comment: If you update your $PATH using .bashrc or .zshrc, does it get picked up by IO.popen("echo $PATH") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. Apparently ENV is not a hash but an Object.

I had two PATHs so ENV had two keys with PATH (I didn't know this was possible).
Removed the last PATH variable and it seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 3):

It gets the PATH from the environment you give it, so give it one:

```
IO.popen(ENV, "echo $PATH").read.chomp
```

or

```
new_env = {'PATH' => '/path/to/foo'}
IO.popen(new_env, "echo $PATH").read.chomp
```

For example:

```
IO.popen({'PATH' => 'foo'},"echo $PATH").read.chomp
# => "foo"
```

This is the first parameter in [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-popen):

```
popen([env,] cmd, mode="r" [, opt]) → io 
popen([env,] cmd, mode="r" [, opt]) {|io| block } → obj
```

It's not clearly specified, but that's what this means:

> The array can contains a hash at first for environments and a hash at last for options similar to spawn.

If you don't pass the environment information, Ruby will use the default `ENV` hash passed to it to create an environment. I see that as a security choice allowing you to limit access, or change environment information for the called code.

```
=> "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

looks like what the root user sees. Generally root runs with a very restricted path.

Comment: It's a normal user account in OSX. I updated the question as well. I didn't understand the security part of the answer. Could you elaborate?